# WCF service discovery with message security

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, service-discovery

I have a client-server application based on WCF where I'm using ServiceDiscovery to find the server from the client. During development with security turned off discovery was working fine but when we turned on message security based on certificates the ServiceDiscovery stopped working.

When I searched for a solution I found this MSDN article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791%28v=vs.110%29.aspx where it says;

> When using message level security it is necessary to specify an EndpointIdentity on the service discovery endpoint and a matching EndpointIdentity on the client discovery endpoint. For more information about message level security, see Message Security in WCF.

I have been searching, reading and writing code but I can't seem to get this into working code. Any ideas?

Exctract of original server code:

```
private Binding CreateBinding()
{
    WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.Message);
    // Set other binding properties
    return binding;
}

private static void EnableServiceDiscovery(ServiceHostBase host)
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
}
```

Compact extract of original client code:

```
public IEnumerable<MyServiceEndpoint> FindServicesOnNetwork()
{
    DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    var myServiceEndpoints = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof (IMyService))).Endpoints;
    discoveryClient.Close();
    return myServiceEndpoints.Select(endpoint => new MyServiceEndpoint(endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString())).ToList();
}
```